# How can I make a C++ countdown timer that doesn't freeze user input?

Tags: c++, input, timer

I'm planning to use the `Sleep()` function to implement a countdown timer. But this freezes the input of the user at the same time. Thus I wanted to ask if it is possible to have the countdown still running in realtime, whether they're typing or not; or in other words not freeze everything.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Example : Pop Quiz with Timer

Comment: I don't  understand the question.

Comment: For starters, use clock instead and find the time difference between each call. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/

Comment: Please elaborate.  Is your problem that the `Sleep` function halts the program, or that receiving input halts the program?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to do this by having a few variables:

```
float countdownDuration = 1.0f;
float cooldown = coutdownDuration;
```

Each frame, you subtract `deltaTime`, or the time that has passed since the last frame, from `cooldown`.  When `cooldown` reaches `0` or below, your countdown timer has 'ticked' down, and you can reset `cooldown` to `countdownDuration` minus the value below `0` that `cooldown` has reached.  In this particular case, by the way I initialized the variables above, each tick will be one second.

In this way, you do not have to `sleep` the main thread and will still check for input every frame.